# How to add content to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to set up a menu website for an assignment and want to make a floating side div for the order summary

Figma reference : https://images2.imgbox.com/59/9f/qikiR5qq_o.jpg

Note: This is the first class with any coding so I'm really new to this.

I have the div and grid set up but can't add the content without messing things up.

The buttons at the bottom are always either not at the bottom or too bottom that it passes the div. Is the problem the div or the content?

Is there a way to remove the item using the remove button? I guess that's javascript?

I copied the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/93bqypdu/1/

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div>
<div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div>
<div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div>
<div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div><div class="a">a</div>
</div>

<div class="side">
<img src="https://images2.imgbox.com/f6/96/uf0fayVE_o.png" width="150vh" 
height="auto" class="pic">
<div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<div class="sbutt">
CANCEL
</div>

<div class="sbutt">
ORDER
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't understand  "The buttons at the bottom are always either not at the bottom or too bottom " i mean what are you expecting to achieve

Comment: @SirDad It's either like in the middle of the div or outside of the bottom of the div

Comment: @Paulie_D Added it sorry

Comment: You don't seem to be using any of the bootstrap classes...so why is it tagged?

Comment: @Piyuem there are no buttons on your code you mean the "a" divs ?

Comment: @SirDad Yeah! I want to link it so I used div instead

Comment: It's not clear what the item being removed (with JavaScript?) has to do with the div issue. If it's not related then you should ask about it in a separate question. Also, "Note: This is the first class with any coding so I'm really new to this" is meta. You should edit that out ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the misaligned Order & Cancel buttons in your fiddle, we will need to add an additional div container for the buttons and assign additional classes to the buttons:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
</div>

<div class="side">
  <img src="https://images2.imgbox.com/f6/96/uf0fayVE_o.png" width_="150vh" height="auto" class="pic">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>

  <div class="sbutt-container">
    <div class="sbutt cancel" onclick="window.location.href = 'Hiveworks.html';">
      CANCEL
    </div>

    <div class="sbutt order" onclick="window.open('dashboard.html', '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=100,left=800,width=380,height=380',overflow=hidden)">
      ORDER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.side {
  right: 1px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 26vw;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #EFA078;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 51%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.pic {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sbutt-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sbutt {
  background-color: #EFA078;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.cancel {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
}

.order {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 69vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  float: left;
}

.a {
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Watch it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/q4n9rxhg/